# How to I generate .jsp from .clas or .java

Tags: java

I am setting an application that is listed as not compatible with my OS (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).
I went throug war files and fixed all erros that I was getting.
At the end, application should open a file named

```
/adminsite/servlet/com.jsbsoft.jtf.core.SG
404 Not found
```

I have

```
/adminsite/... with several .jsp files and directories
```

and

```
com.jsbsoft.jtf.core.SG.class in classes directories
```

I see that I am missing the servlet directory under adminsite, so I created that directory, and placed com.jsbsoft.jtf.core.SG.class inside, it give me a bunch of errors.
So I guess I should generate jsp files inside /adminsite/servlet.
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is that compilers translate jsp -> java -> class (and some of them do not even bother to show you the java code).
Going backwards could work as much as class -> java (), but for sure not up to the jsp code. You want to search for a Java Decompiler.

On the other hand you do not need to go back to the jsp file as that one is still present in your webapplication. As you mentioned, there are multiple jsp files already.

Therefore I believe you are searching for a lot of things and may be overlooking something. That would not be a surprise as reverse engineering is a demanding task.